# Does Proxy re-encryption can re-encrypt large data?

Tags: elliptic-curves, proxy-re-encryption

Many resources talk about the benefit of Proxy Re-encryption (PRE) and I also implement my PRE using Elliptic Curve key pair. But after I set up Global parameters, I can encrypt very small data maybe less than 1KB. My question is with EC key pair normally, can we encrypt large data maybe about 10MB?

Comment: Usually proxy re-encryption is used to encrypt smaller data like a symmetric encryption key, not a full message or file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally the data is not encrypted under PRE directly. The sender can encrypt the data using a random symmetric key using a secure symmetric cipher (e.g. AES), then encrypts the symmetric key under the sender's PRE key. The proxy can re-encrypt this ciphertext into a new ciphertext such that the receiver can decrypt it.

Comment: Could you please tell how exactly this trick is happening?